# How to convert the list index into integer numbers in earth engine Javascript

Tags: javascript, list, int

Suppose I have a list with variable `t`.

```
var t = [1,2,3]
```

I want to convert this list into integer numbers.

I don't want this: `[1]`

I want this: `1`

Comment: Can you add sample code that gives you the `[1]` that you see and don’t want?

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over that array and get the value for each item.

Example:

```js
var t = [1,2,3]

for(i=0; i<t.length; i++) {
    console.log(t[i]);
}
```

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as accepted so others know that is the correct solution to your question?